# next_/previous_post_link() `in_same_category` appears to fail when true

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, page-template

I'm using the [Modernize](http://themes.goodlayers.com/?theme=modernize) theme's custom Portfolio type page. In the `single-portfolio.php` template, I call `next_` and `previous_post_link()`, which correctly display links when in_same_category is set to `false`, but when set to `true` they are blank.

There are other pages in the same category as the page currently being viewed, though some pages may belong to multiple categories.

Did I miss something obvious?

This shows the following link:

```
<?php
previous_post_link('<div class="single-port-prev-nav"><div class="left-arrow"></div>%link</div>', '%title', false);
next_post_link('<div class="single-port-next-nav">%link<div class="right-arrow"></div></div>', '%title', false);
```

This does not show the following link:

```
<?php
previous_post_link('<div class="single-port-prev-nav"><div class="left-arrow"></div>%link</div>', '%title', true);
next_post_link('<div class="single-port-next-nav">%link<div class="right-arrow"></div></div>', '%title', true);
```

**However**, after looking a little more, I wonder if multiple category taxonomies might be playing a role in this. I can't think of another reason for this not to behave as expected correctly than incorrectly configured categories.

Comment: Can you show code?

Comment: @vancoder I've spent enough time on SO that I shouldn't have forgotten that! Checking it out again has all but convinced me that the problem lies in the category taxonomy.